# Run a command on local machine while on ssh in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to run a command on local system while I have ssh'd to a remote system in bash. Is there a way to do this? This is what I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh mysystem@ip <<'SSH'
#Do something
#Run a command here on local machine and not on machine I have sshed to
#Do Something

exit
SSH
```

Edit: I want to echo some message and since echo command output won't show from remote machine, I want to run from local.

Comment: you can do the other way around: stay local and send commands to the remote

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? While answering this question might let you proceed with whatever it is, this sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). It's entirely possible that we can help you solve it a better way if you give us more information.

Comment: I added more details of what I want to do

Comment: What do you mean that "echo won't show from remote machine"? Unless the ssh command has more going on than you provide here, stdout and stderr are both copied back to the local system.

Comment: By default, standard output for any commands on the remote host is whatever the `ssh` command uses for standard output.

Comment: ...can you amend your question to include code that **actually reproduces the problem**? Because if I just put an `echo "This is a test"` inside the heredoc run over ssh, that would work fine (running the echo on the remote end, but copying it back over the ssh channel to the local machine).

Comment: I see the command 'echo "This is a test"' and not the output. "This is a test". Do I need to set some flag or something?

Comment: Please provide the full, complete, *exact* command you're running, complete with invocation method -- having the command echo'd at all is unusual (without `set -x` or similar).

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7fb5899ba48b5e0f4465684f1b4fcc1 for an example of the behavior I get (and expect) in similar situations. Now, granted, it's possible for your specific remote host to be configured with non-default behavior, but someone would have had to go out of their way to set that up.

Comment: What I see in output is commands I have typed under ssh followed by the '>' as in the gitub page. There are a bunch of commands which do run but I don't see any message on terminal in case they are giving one.

Comment: I mean there is a command to scp which does the scp but echo won't show the mesage

Comment: I even tried the script on a different system but same thing. Looks like output is suppressed for some reason. I am not able to copy the script since a part of it copyrighted material but what I wrote in question or you put in github is the gist. Just that the last line doesn't show up for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

WHen you are using SSH, the key sequence  `<enter>~` is a escape prefix that allows you to pause SSH and send key sequences to the ssh client on the host-side.
The sequence `<enter>~<ctrl + z>` will pause (stop) the ssh-client job and drop you to a prompt in the calling system. Typing `fg` (if ou are on a Unix shell) will resume your ssh session afterwards.

You can see other ssh escape sequences avaiable by typing  `<enter>~?`.
The sequence `<enter>~.` will terminate the connection and is very handy when your session is locked on the remote machine.

(Users with non-US keyboard layouts that use  `~` as a dead-key to compose accents and digrams have, obviously,  to type `~` twice in all of these sequences)

These sequences are of use from when you are operating the SSH session an d typign commands yourself, not for scripting.

Since you seem to want a way to that in scripts, the straightforward solution is to include an `ssh` command back to the originating host.

Comment: I basically wanted to echo something in an automated script. echo won't run on remote machine

Comment: no - these sequences are for when you are "live" at the terminal, not for scripting.

Answer (score 3):

I have an approach which is pretty hacky, but it works.

**Overview and security caveats**

In brief, you use [reverse SSH tunnelling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work) to SSH back to your local machine and [run a single command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119894/single-command-to-login-to-ssh-and-run-program/119899), and you connect back using your SSH keys so that no password is required.

NB This approach involves agent forwarding, which comes with [a risk](https://smallstep.com/blog/ssh-agent-explained/#:%7E:text=Agent%20forwarding%20comes%20with%20a,other%20machines%20on%20the%20network.):

> anyone with root access on the remote host can discreetly access your local SSH agent through the socket. They can use your keys to impersonate you on other machines on the network.

The risk is lessened in your case because the SSH session is only open for the duration of the command. But I'm not a security expert so can't comment further.

An alternative would be to generate a specific keypair just for this connection and use that, but I'm not sure how scriptable this would be.

The second security caveat is that this approach involves running an SSH server on your local machine. See my notes at the end of this answer for more on that.

**Details**

First of all, your SSH command needs some extra parameters:

```
ssh mysystem@ip -A -R 2900:localhost:22
```

`-A` forwards your credentials ([detailed article on agent forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html)). You'll use them when connecting back to your local machine.

`-R 2900:localhost:22` sets up the reverse tunnel. This means that on the remote machine you can run `ssh -p2900 yourlocaluser@localhost` and it'll SSH back to your local machine. Replace `yourlocaluser` with the user from your host machine (not the machine you're SSHing into). I picked 2900 as an arbitrary port. It needs to be higher than 1024, I think.

To avoid typing these every time, you can set them in your SSH config (`~/.ssh/config`) on your local machine. These are the relevant properties:

```
  ForwardAgent yes
  RemoteForward 2900 localhost:22
```

Also, you need to tell your local machine that SSH connections are allowed to connect to it using its own key pair(!) To do this, add the contents of your public key file (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

You can now connect to your remote machine and run a command like this to connect back to your local one:

```sh
ssh -t -p2900 yourlocaluser@localhost <command here>
```

Note, however, that the first time you connect back from the remote machine to your local one using the key, you'll get a warning that the host you're connecting to is unknown. Once you say that you want to continue connecting, it'll save the relevant details to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on the remote machine and not ask again.

You could log in and manually do an SSH to get the details saved. Alternatively, you can update the SSH command that you run on the remote machine, but it comes with an additional security caveat.

Here's the updated command:

```sh
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -t -p2900 yourlocaluser@localhost <command here>
```

The security risk is that you're accepting the key without reviewing it and making sure that it's what you're expecting, so you're vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. Again, I'm no security expert, but given that you're connecting using an SSH tunnel rather than a regular SSH connection, I believe that this reduces the risk. If the known hosts file on the remote machine only contains the entry for your local machine, you could update your SSH config to replace the contents of that file with [your local machine's key fingerprint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631286/392741) from your local machine on login, and then remove `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` from the above.

Note: If you're prompted for your password when trying to SSH back, that suggests that agent forwarding hasn't worked. You probably need to run [`ssh-add`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) on your local machine or update your local SSH config for the host in question to include [`AddKeysToAgent yes`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269132/392741).

**Note about running sshd on your local machine**

The above assumes that you're running `sshd` on your local machine, and thus accepting SSH connections to that machine. That's a security risk in itself. One way of reducing that risk is to specify that SSH is only allowed from localhost, which will work in this case because you're tunnelling back. You can find instructions on how to configure your local SSH server for this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/179325/accepting-ssh-connections-only-from-localhost

You could also adapt the answer here and use netcat rather than SSH: https://superuser.com/a/1274810/126533

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the script, you can use an expect script for that - [expect_example_and_tips](https://www.pantz.org/software/expect/expect_examples_and_tips.html)

This allows you to start an "ssh process" to which can send commands to the remote machine, while still running on the local machine.

Much easier in python though in my opinion - example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pexpect

PROMPT = "\$|\%|\>"
ssh_cmd = "ssh user@192.168.1.1"

try:
     ssh = pexpect.spawn(ssh_cmd)
     ssh.sendline("echo hello on remote")
     ssh.expect(PROMPT)
     print "hello on local machine"
     ssh.close()

except Exception as e:
     print e
     sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: I just wanted to echo something while running remote commands.

Comment: So use expect to run the remote commands as I suggested and you can echo as you wish since you are on the local machine. I'm afraid I don't know another way to bypass this - I did the same first in Bash then in Python using the pexpect module - very convenient to use.

Comment: So your answer is "you can use this other tool, and here's a link, but I wouldn't use either this or the thing you're asking about, I'd use something else entirely for which I've provided no examples"?  Um...  Would you care to improve your answer?

Comment: You are right - I added a python example. Don't have a bash example with pexpect right now, so if bash is preferred I think the tutorial + man pexpect in any linux machine is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to (for argument's sake) run `date` locally, just don't quote the here document, and any command substitution will be executed locally.

```sh
ssh mysystem@ip <<SSH  # notice absence of quotes
   echo I am logged in from $(uname -n) since $(date)
SSH
```

Here, the `uname` and `date` commands will be executed locally, before the `ssh` command runs, whereas the `echo` in the here document will then execute remotely.

(As an aside, there is no need to explicitly `exit` at the end; the shell will exit when it reaches the end of input. It's hard to imagine a scenario where anything else would make any sense whatsoever.)